# php files not running in windows server 2003 scheduled tasks

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

I try to run abc.php file with scheduled task in windows server 2003.
I tried from command promt ;
<kbd>schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "mytask" /tr "C:\PATHOFPHP\php.exe C:\wamp..\abc.php"</kbd> still not working 
Also i tried the other way 
<kbd>start->programs->accesories->system tools ->scheduled tasks.</kbd> not working.
In my task window ; 
<kbd>run: php5.3.13\php.exe c:\wamp\www..\abc.php</kbd>
<kbd>start in : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

Open -> Control panel - > Administrative Tools - > task Scheduler

open task Scheduler and create new basic task as below screen shot :
[image]

```
2) after that select Daily and click next
3) Specify the start date and end date click next
4) Action program click next
```

[image]

```
5) Start a Program browse Program/Script, here in this section create one test.bat file with the following content as below and browse here.

@echo off
"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
sleep1
start "webpage name" "http://www.google.com/"
```

in the above example I am using google page you can use your php page.

```
6) click finish
```

Comment: @echo off
"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
sleep1
start "webpage name" "http://localhost/abc/def.php/"  i wrote this to bat file and it worked! thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `.bat` file and run it on your schedule: `Open -> Control panel - > Administrative Tools - > task Scheduler`

Here is an example of how you would do it:

```
@echo off
start "abc.php running" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\wwwroot\reminder-email.php
```

Comment: ıt run something without error message but in my php code, Code must mail to me,but mail didn't reached to me

Comment: could i see the code please (sorry about reply delay)

Comment: you mean php code? I tried to send but its to long to send from here

Comment: add relevant parts of the PHP code which went wrong below your question and explain your new problem in detail please do not add it as an answer!

Comment: You understand wrong, it didn't work. When i run it manually it works. But with your way it is not working. So there is no problem with my php code.